# is there a way to use fixed-length index in logback's rolling filename pattern?

Tags: logback

is there a way to use fixed-length index in logback's rolling filename pattern?
I mean rolled log-files will be indexed like:

```
application-2021-07-14_01.log.gz
application-2021-07-14_02.log.gz
application-2021-07-14_03.log.gz
...
application-2021-07-14_10.log.gz
application-2021-07-14_11.log.gz
...
```

instead of:

```
application-2021-07-14_1.log.gz
application-2021-07-14_2.log.gz
application-2021-07-14_3.log.gz
...
application-2021-07-14_10.log.gz
application-2021-07-14_11.log.gz
...
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: You might want to look at http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpFileNamePattern

Comment: @Progman, thank you. I checked it already, It is not mentioned there. Do you want to tell me it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `fileNamePattern` like this:

```
// left justified, missing zeroes
<fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%-2i.log</fileNamePattern>
// zero left-pad with 2 places
<fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%02i.log</fileNamePattern>
```

or

```
<fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i{2}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

As mentinoned [in the docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy) but spreading it with [the percent/formatter syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: thank you, unfortunately no one of 3 proposed methods seems to be working with logback 1.2.3

Comment: I just returned to the issue and with most recent version of logback which is currenty 1.2.11 it works. It looks like it was fixed in version 1.2.4 released 5 days after I posted my question :)